# Gdpr Error , Consent form error - Publisher misconfiguration

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform

I use admob ads in my android app and before admob ads request sent, call gdpr form with this sdk:

> com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform

When i run and test it with this:

> val debugSettings =
> ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(activity)
> .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
> .addTestDeviceHashedId("-----------------")
> .build()
> val params =
> ConsentRequestParameters.Builder().setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings).build()

Thats ok and load Consent form.
But when i load app without test form, i receive this error:

> Publisher misconfiguration: Failed to read publisher's account
> configuration; no form(s) configured for the input app ID. Verify that
> you have configured one or more forms for this application and try
> again. Received app ID: ----------

And don't show Consent form and i cant send admob request and show it.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Could [this](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/ErxnuJ77rFg) help?

Comment: @tomerpacific Thanks for your comment. no, my problem solved by fill gdpr form

Comment: Did the comment help?

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by fill gdpr form in admob panel and add form for my app id in admob panel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).